# How to connect windows phone 8 to remote database?

Tags: web-services, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have a project for final course in windows phone 8, where I need to connect to an online database, currently I am using windows azure for this purpose but you can not access directly can not even do it for a mobile service azure. 
Wanted to know if I can help find a solution and where the meeting or something to look for.

Thank you, 
BM7000

Comment: Your question is unclear, could you reword it to better explain to us what you want?

Comment: What database are you using in Windows Azure? And are you encountering a specific error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need connect to a online database, you must not connect to that directly. You need a backend  between the database and the Windows phone applicaton.

Azure mobile services is one of the best solutions and the most simple to do this.

In your WP App only need install the azure mobile services sdk via nuget. Create the tables through classes and manage that whit the sdk.

The best way to understand and learn how to do this, is to read the official documentation of the site of Azure.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-wp8

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for mobile devices is to use a service layer to connect to a backend database.  Azure Mobile Services let you do that.